# robocopy batch file to get all local disks and backup

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

I have this code,

```
For /F "tokens=1" %%I In ('wmic logicaldisk get DeviceID^,DriveType^|Findstr "3"') Do (
If Exist "%%I" robocopy %%I "%dest%\%%I"  /MIR /IS /XA:SH /XD "!dirs!" /XF "!files!" /R:3 /W:3 /TEE /log+:"%srclog%\%logfile%" /NP
)
```

However robocopy reads the source to backup as the current user's profile path so i.e. Source: C:\Users\Administrator instead of the wanted C:\

Also, how do I set the variables as just the letters and with the :\ ? This is for creating the folders in the backup destination so I can sort them by the drive alphabets...

Comment: Hard to make any recommendations without seeing all your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%%I` receives the `DeviceID` of the disks, which is nothing but the drive letter followed by a colon, like `C:`. This constitutes a relative path. To make it an absolute one pointing to the root directory of the drive, simply append a backslash, like `C:\`. So in your code `%%I` becomes `%%I\`.

For the other part of the question, to extract the pure drive letter only, you need an interim variable to do that, like `drive`, for instance, then you can apply [sub-string expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html), like `%drive:~,1%`. **But** since this happens in a block of code, you need to apply [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html), like `!drive:~,1!` (since you are already using delayed expansion for `!dirs!` and `!files!`, I assume you already have the command line `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` somewhere in your script):

```
for /F "tokens=1" %%I in ('wmic LogicalDisk GET DeviceID^,DriveType ^| findstr "3"') do (
    set "drive=%%I"
    if exist "%%I\" robocopy "%%I\" "%dest%\!drive:~,1!" /MIR /IS /XA:SH /XD "!dirs!" /XF "!files!" /R:3 /W:3 /TEE /log+:"%srclog%\%logfile%" /NP
)
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer, had to modify a few quote marks ehre and there but it's working :) Appreciate that!

Comment: Im wondering if you can help me. It worked well the other day but now, it gives me an error 2016/09/26 09:23:19 ERROR 87 (0x00000057) Creating Destination Directory \\dir\dir\dir\C\
The parameter is incorrect. This is when Im copying the first drive (C:\) but it copies the D:\ fine.. Any ideas?

Comment: Realized I got it fixed when it ran as admin. How do I make it so it can do the same w/o admin rights?

Comment: okay, it works now, and I didnt even do a thing. I wish there was an explanation for this though,